# The inverse map of the Poincare duality map

Tags: algebraic-topology, duality-theorems, module-isomorphism, poincare-duality

Let $M$ be an oriented compact smooth manifold of dimension $n$. Let $[M]$ be the fundamental class of $M$, that is, $[M]\in H_n(M, \mathbb Z)$. Then, the Poincare duality map is the isomorphism given by
$$
H^p(M, \mathbb Z)\to H_{n-p}(M, \mathbb Z), 
\quad 
[\alpha]\mapsto[\alpha]\frown[M].
$$

Is the inverse of the above map known and can it be explicitly defined?

Answer (score 1):

Let $|-\cap^{trans}-|$ denote the operation of counting signed intersections of transverse representatives of embedded simplicial complexes of complementary dimension. The inverse map is given by sending a class $[\sigma]$ to the adjoint of its intersection pairing, i.e. the cohomology class of the cocyle $\rho \rightarrow |\rho \cap^{trans} \sigma|$.  For more information, see section 3.6 of [Whitney Stratified Chains and Cochains](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1981-267-01/S0002-9947-1981-0621981-X/S0002-9947-1981-0621981-X.pdf).